# Share information between fragments

Tags: android, shared

I need to share information between fragments. I know that I can use sharedpreferences but I think that is not optimized.

This is the parent fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

  ....
  FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();               
  ft.replace(R.id.eventos_pager, new BlankFragment2());                       
  ft.commit();
  ....
    return view;
}
```

This fragment call BlankFragment2 and BlankFragment1 need to sends information to BlankFragment2

I can share information to BlankFragment2 by the BlankFragment2's constructor. It is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android you pass values to Fragments via bundles.

Using AndroidStudio `File > New > Fragment > Fragment (Blank)` will generate something like this.

```
public class MTFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mParam1;

    public static MTFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        MTFragment fragment = new MTFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("value", param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString("value");
        }
    }

}
```

From your code:

```
MTFragment mFragment = MTFragment.newInstance("Hello");

FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();              
ft.replace(R.id.eventos_pager, mFragment);                       
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks. What I can get that code is the BlankFragment2's code (the fragment that get the data) and how I send that information from BlankFragment1?

Comment: It depends. You mention that you want to pass it via constructor right? I update my post

Comment: thanks but How can I get "hello" from the second or child fragment?

Comment: I don't get it. Hello is hold by the variable ```mParam1``` . So you can use it anywhere you want. For example in ```onViewCreated```